# Unable to add data to MYSQL database from JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I'm new with PHP. I'v been struggling with this task for hours now. Earlier I used json_encode to get data from MYSQL to a JSON file. Now i try to revese and add the same data from JSON file to a new MYSQL database. I have a problem with converting the array to string before passing it to MYSQL database tho. The database works and I was able to add "players" there by inserting manual values instead of the $values from array. My code looks like this:

```
<?php
//open connection to mysql db
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","scoreboard2") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

$scorefile = file_get_contents('scores.json');
$Score = json_decode($scorefile, true);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($Score, true) . '</pre>';

foreach ($Score as $field => $value) {
    // Use $field and $value here

    print_r($field . '=>' . $value . '<br/>', true);

    //mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO scores (name, score, time) VALUES ($value->name, $value->score, $value->time)");
}

//mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

the JSON file looks like this:

```
[
 {"id":"22",
  "name":"Jack",
  "score":"2142",
  "time":"196:13",
  "ts":"2016-02-23 15:36:23",
  "date":"2016-02-23"},

 {"id":"23",
  "name":"Bob",
  "score":"7026",
  "time":"35:54",
  "ts":"2016-02-23 15:40:33"}
]
```

etc.. and the "error" is this:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\JSON_MySQL\decode.php on line 13

Comment: why do you have 2 commented out lines of code here? check for errors on your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - strings need to be quoted in values.

Comment: The query is commented out just because it's not working and causing more errors to the page. Don't know why the connection closing is but should not really matter.

Comment: again; string values need to be quoted. check for errors using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  on the query

Comment: If you don't want to deal with strings at all you can use [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are converting the data in your .json file to an array by using parameter 2 of `json_decode()` as `true`.

This is converting your objects to arrays and therefore the syntax you use in this line is wrong

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO scores 
                           (name, score, time) 
                    VALUES ($value->name, $value->score, $value->time)");
```

because you are using object notation.

So change this line from

```
$Score = json_decode($scorefile, true);
```

To

```
$Score = json_decode($scorefile);
```

SO

```
?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","scoreboard2") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

$scorefile = file_get_contents('scores.json');
$Score = json_decode($scorefile);

foreach ($Score as $object) {

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO scores 
                               (name, score, time) 
                        VALUES ('{$object->name}', '{$object->score}', '{$object->time}')");
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Also note I quoted the values with single quotes and also wrapped the object properties in `{}` which is required when using object or array notation inside a double quoted literal.

Comment: well, first the line spotted by the error isn't the one with the request, moreover it's commented, so if your answer actually is the correct one, then the question is very poorly asked (because the code given isn't the one producing the error)

Comment: You beat me by a milli second _my old ship mate_ @Fred-ii-

Comment: Allright this worked like charm thanks! Just had to change the "$value" to "$object" inside the mysqli_query :)

Comment: @Guiroux I have to assume the questioner commented out the code that was causing him trouble and then added the `print_r()` stuff. It is necessary to read between the lines every now and again

Comment: *Putting wind in your sails there Smokey!* @RiggsFolly ;-)

Comment: @juwss Woops. Typo alert. Thanks fixed it.

Comment: why was this answer downvoted????? "That" somebody needs to give an explanation here, that's if they "have balls" or integrity that is.

Comment: well, I'm very sorry for you but the "petty downvote" as you said wasn't from me. You know, just like I didn't actually said that you were wrong I was just pointing out some inconsistencies between the question and answer, that's all, and read again, he said the commented section is `causing more errors` which may mean that he has the error **even** with the lines commented

Comment: @Guiroux Ok apologise, again I was just assuming. Not always a good idea I guess.

Comment: if he confirms that he wasn't actually having any errors with the exact code he posted in the original question, I will gladly upvote your post

Comment: well I for one didn't name anyone. I said *"That" somebody*. The answer is correct 100%, and if it was just because of some typos that were fixed, well... that's more than just petty.

Comment: @Guiroux I was not begging for an upvote, just wanted to know what someone thought was wrong with the answer. I guess it was my typo.

Comment: I didn't accuse you of begging, but if your answer is perfectly correct, I can't see why i wouldn't upvote it
@Fred-ii- you accused no one in particular indeed, I never use the @ to answer people and it can cause misunderstanding

Comment: @Guiroux True. My Mama's the one who taught me "diplomacy" ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- by the way how can you state that *The answer is correct 100%* while we don't even know what code produced the error ? Ok the answer works because he replaced **ALL** the previous code by new one, but the fact that the new code works doesn't means that the only problem was the one pointed out

Comment: @Guiroux because, it's pretty obvious here. This `($value->name, $value->score, $value->time)` as I stated in comments up there that string values must be quoted. So, why are we still talking about this?

Comment: @Guiroux You obviously know something we don't, so why don't you post your own answer then and let the OP decide. *"Put your money where you mouth is"* I always say.

Comment: **Can we call a halt to this please** I have moved on, the questioner has moved on, the downvoter has moved on, lets all do the same.

Comment: the thing is I wasn't sure, because i couldn't test, and as I would never declare that something is "100% correct" unless I actually can prove that it's true, I was just trying to create a discussion to get the truth, now that I tested this code, and that I can confirm that **the commented version posted in the question produce the exact error**, I can affirm instead of just trying to argue, you could say *his code resolve this so why bother ?* Well, I bother cause OP would probably use again print_r wrongly if you just erase the part where he use it and say *look, my code works fine*

Answer (score 1):

The error

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   F:\XAMPP\htdocs\JSON_MySQL\decode.php on line 13

is produced by the line

`print_r($field . '=>' . $value . '<br/>', true);`

(which actually is the 13th line)

where you try to convert `$value` which is an array (your second score object) to a string in order to concatenate it with the rest of the string

note that if you replace the error-producing line by

```
echo '<pre>' .$field . '=>' . print_r($value, true) . '</pre>'.'<br/>';
```

you get the

```
0=>Array
(
    [id] => 22
    [name] => Jack
    [score] => 2142
    [time] => 196:13
    [ts] => 2016-02-23 15:36:23
    [date] => 2016-02-23
)

1=>Array
(
    [id] => 23
    [name] => Bob
    [score] => 7026
    [time] => 35:54
    [ts] => 2016-02-23 15:40:33
)
```

that you might originally expect